# Xcode (lldb) How to find who hold object by memory address

Tags: swift, swiftui, lldb

Assuming I have the following code

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 20){ 
            Button(action: action, label: displayText)
        }
    }
     @ViewBuilder
    func displayText() -> some View  {
        Text("Label Button")
    }
    
    func action() -> Void  {
        withUnsafePointer(to: action) {adr in            
            print("address: \(adr)")
            print(String(format: "address formatted: %p", adr))
        }
    }
}
```

I get the address of my function but how can I know which object is actually holding it?
 For instance in UIKit I could get all the actions from my UIButton but who is holding it in swiftUI?
I have looked in object memory graph
*image lockup -a* also doesnt help
I would assume that: *e -l swift -O --* will at least print the object description (but that also is only a number). 
I guess it's the EventBindingManager

Comment: My purpose is to highlight those clickable elements. (assuming I would like to scan the page and discover those elements )

Comment: sorry about not being clear, My goal is to find which elements can be clickable on screen and highlight them (for instance  Button would be considered as clickable).
So My first assumption would be to see which elements may have a callback/action

Comment: I currently have the ability to track when the click  happens(without any  change of the above code ), but that not enough